# Sequence syntax to use larger value

Tags: sql, db2, sequence

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SAS.SEQUENCE  
START WITH 7000000000  
INCREMENT BY 1  
MINVALUE 7000000000  
NO MAXVALUE  
NO CYCLE  
NOCACHE;
```

I get the this error
SQL0846N  Invalid specification of an identity column or sequence object "SEQUENCE" "SAS.SEQUENCE". Reason code = "2".  SQLSTATE=42815

Comment: 7000000000  is too big for a regular integer. Do you need to specify bigint data type?

Comment: Yes you are right i want to use bigint data type. How to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

7000000000 is too big for a regular integer. Specify bigint data type!

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SAS.SEQUENCE
AS BIGINT  
START WITH 7000000000  
INCREMENT BY 1  
MINVALUE 7000000000  
NO MAXVALUE  
NO CYCLE  
NOCACHE;
```

Comment: Perfect Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

$ db2 "? SQL0846N  "

SQL0846N  Invalid specification of an identity column or sequence object
      "" "". Reason code = "".

Explanation:

For an identity column or sequence object, the specification of an
attribute in a CREATE or ALTER statement may be invalid for one of the
following reasons:

2. The value for START WITH, INCREMENT BY, MINVALUE or MAXVALUE is
   outside of the range for the data type of the identity column or
   sequence object.

User response:

Correct the syntax and resubmit the statement.

Your 'START WITH' value looks quite huge.

Comment: my requirement is to use this value. do we have any other way to use this value in sequence ?